# Open with code is not working in VSCode - Application not found

Tags: visual-studio-code

When i right click to open my project folder in VSCode, it is not opening, instead popup is shown as "Application not found". I tried reinstalling, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your project from File-> Open Folder menu in VS code. Than double click on your loaded project files.

Comment: that is not a good way. If i want to open another project folder, i need to open new VSCode window and File-> Open Folder. I need that option "Open with code" working.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this after a reinstall of VS Code. I had switched from the User Installer to the System Installer version.
[Image of current download optons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwgQM.jpg)
The install didn't update the registry to change the Icon and "Open with Code" context menu to use the new path to Code.exe.

So you have a couple options. Reinstall your initial version (User vs System) or update your registry anywhere Code.exe is referenced.

**User path**: *C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe*

**System path**: *C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe*

Or perhaps even uninstall, clear out the references to Code.exe in your Registry, then install the version you'd like

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :
search for your setup file for Re-installation of vs code which will be already available in your PC Named As VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.59.1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).